# Too many try/catch block for PDO

Tags: php, error-handling, pdo, try-catch

In the controllers class files, most of the method functions include try/catch block something like this:

```
 try
   {
      $stmt = $this->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute($params);
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      //foreach() or so on...
   }
   catch (Exception $e)
   {
      //bunch of code...
      //save error into database, etc.
      //error into json and pass to view file
   }
```

There are a lot of code in the catch block, is there a way to reduce it. Is possible to add "throw exception" in the catch block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Try it by yourself. You can always throw a new Exception in a catch block or rethrow the same exception.

```
try
   {
      // ...
   }
   catch (Exception $e)
   {
      // do whatever you want
      throw new Your_Exception($e->getMessage());
      // or
      throw $e;
   }
```

Comment: How do I create Your_Exception.. ?

Comment: @user791022 `class Your_Exception extends Exception {}`, or you can use [SPL exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what "bunch of code" is.  I'm not sure I believe you.  If you have that much going on in a catch block you're doing something wrong.

I'd put this kind of code into an aspect if you have AOP available to you.

"Error into database" might throw its own exception.  What happens to that?

The only step that I see here that's necessary is routing to the error view.

What does rethrowing the exception do?  It's just passing the buck somewhere else.  If all these steps don't need to be done, and all you're doing to rethrowing, then don't catch it at all.  Let the exception bubble up to where it's truly handled.

Comment: Rethrowing exceptions is explicit, and demonstrates intent; "I knew this code could possibly fail, but don't want/need to handle the failure here."  Simply leaving it out is ambiguous and can lead to hard-to-follow logic.

Comment: Leaving it out says "I can't handle it; I won't pretend to.  Let it bubble up to someone who can."  It's not ambiguous at all.  I think catching and re-throwing means useless lines of code, a waste, and doesn't improve the logic at all.

Comment: On the contrary, leaving it out could be either intentional or unintentional.  That's how it's ambiguous.  When looking at the code, how do you know the developer didn't just forget to handle a potential exception?  If you're the sole developer, it isn't (as big of) an issue, but lots of us work in teams :)

Comment: I work in teams.  And I can tell by figuring out who called that method and seeing if the exception is handled there.  Some of us use IDEs.

Comment: Great.  And if the exception never gets handled through a significantly deep callstack, what IDE is going to read your development team's minds and tell you which function was supposed to handle it?  While you're busy teaching your IDE telepathy, I'll be content glancing at all my useless rethrows and figuring it out with little effort. :)

Comment: Actually, my way will make the call stack less deep than your way, because it won't include those useless catch blocks that log the error and rethrow it.  Mine include the exception that actually handles the error.  My development team understands well-layered code, so it's not as much of a problem to figure out where things are handled.  Maybe you and your team need some architecture lessons on how to layer an application properly.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be catching `Exception`. That's much too general.  Catch each specific type of Exception with multiple catch statements on your try block:

```
try {


} catch(PDOException $err) {

} catch(DomainException $err) {

}
```